# Cassandra Data-Model - 1 SCF or Multiple CF's

Tags: cassandra

Consider the following, I want to store data about Stone Bricks in Cassandra. First the brick has a unique name/id called brick123. This brick has "dimensions" of width:6, height:3, length:4. Its "weight:2pds." It has some wild "color" basecolor:red, hue:sandstone, striping:blue. It is "produced" in the following countries, 1:Russia, 2:Africa, 3:Japan. We can order it from the following "suppliers" 1:Lowes, 2:bricks-r-us, 3:stone-supply.

Now, if I we have X number of Stone Bricks, should we use a Super-Column-Family to house our Brick data? Would we be able to ask Cassandra for Stone Bricks FROM Africa or what Stone Bricks are available through stone-supply?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal advice seems to be to avoid SCFs in favour of multiple CFs.

For the plain properties of a brick (width, color...), you can use a simple row per brick with a column per property (you could also enable automatic secondary indexes if you want to look up bricks with particular properties):

```
CF "bricks":

brick123 -> w  h  l  weight  color  hue        striping
            6  3  4  2pds    red    sandstone  blue
```

For the multi-valued properties (countries, producers) you could have separate column families:

```
CF "countries":

brick123 -> Russia  Africa  Japan
            <empty> <empty> <empty>
```

And/or if you want to lookup bricks from a given country, you create a secondary index as another CF:

```
CF "country2bricks"

Russia -> brick123  brick124  ...
          <empty>   <empty> 

Africa -> brick123  brick127 ...
          <empty>   <empty> 

Japan  -> brick123
          <empty>
```

(and the same for suppliers)

The key point is that in Cassandra you structure the column families to match the queries you want to perform, denormalising as required.

"empty" indicates that we are just using the column name alone to store information, with an empty column value.

Comment: Thanks DNA! The more I read about and study up upon this issue, it appears like you said, either multiple cf's OR the use of CompositeType column's. CompositeType looks promising except for the lack of support in many of the api's like PHP.

Comment: PHP supports composites now. just make the key like "something:something_else".

Answer (score 1):

Super columns are not indexed - this means, that read access on super column would load its whole content into RAM. This is also another reason to avoid SCF, especially if it contains large amount of data.

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations